# No tooltip with IE10 document mode IE8 Standards

Tags: highcharts

I need help with IE10 and IE8 Standards document mode. 
I've an application with an dashboard which contains some widget, each containing an iframe with an Highcharts chart. 
Because these widgets are reziable, I've some javascript for resizing the container of the charts.

```
    $(window).bind("resize", resizeChart);
    function resizeChart() {
       var width = $(document).width() - 55;
       var height = $(document).height() - 60;
       $("#container").css("width", width);
       $("#container").css("height", height);
    }
```

Some example: http://jsfiddle.net/CwnDw/

In some charts (spline, windrose, polar) I've problems with the tooltip. In windrose and spiderweb charts I've no tooltip. In spline charts 
the tooltip only works at the lower end of the chart. I don't understand why this happens. When I try the Highcharts samples with IE10 and IE8 document mode there is no problem.

Anyone else having problems with IE10 or having an idea what I should try?

Thank you
Torben

Comment: Your example link seems to be wrong. Can you share a valid link to jsFiddle?

Comment: I've added the correct link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was fixed: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2005

Thank you!